# Comparing from one column with one integer in R

Tags: r, if-statement, comparison

I'm seeking to compare a set of values from one column and I need to know if each one is bigger than one, so I can print a warning message that probably there was a typo inserting values in the beginning.

```
i=1:nrow(data)
if (m1$residuals[i] > 1) {
   print("typo")
}
```

This doesn't work, I get this message

> Warning message:
>   In if (m1$residuals[i] > 1) { :
>     the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Why though?

Can someone tell me an alternative way to do it?

Thank you

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see.

```
if(all((m1$residuals>1)==TRUE)){
print("typo")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to know if at least one of the values in the column exceeds 1? If so you could try

```
if (any(m1$residuals > 1)) {
   print('typo')
}
```

If you want to check if *all* the values are greater than 1, replace the 'any' with 'all'.

Comment: Ah! Dind't know about the any().
Thanks a lot! This will do!

Comment: If this works for you, please accept the answer. Thanks.